# How to update the content of a website using the website itself?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, joomla

Is it possible to update the content of a website (add Item, remove Item, update Infos, etc...) directly from the webpage? 
For example, you have a webpage and you make a new page in it, that only the admin can access. That page should contain some options that allow the admin to change/update contents on the actual website(what people can see) easily.
(Without the admin having to write new HTML or PHP code...)

I heard something about Joomla or Wordpress but I don't really know how they work.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you are referring to a CMS, but your question doesn't belong on Stackoverflow as it's asking about not writing code, the exact opposite of this site's purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicaly, joomla has some fonctionnalities to edit content by the frontoffice. Of course, the user need to be logged and access levels need to be well managed. You should to try it with a basic installation and see if it's coherent with respect to that you looking for.